# Complex query in two table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL.

First table is `EMPLOYEES`, it contain such columns as `LASTNAME, NAME, MIDDLENAME, BIRHDATE` and others about employees.

Second table is `PROJECTS`. It has among other things column `STAFF`.
STAFF has rows like 
`lastname1 name1, middlename1; lastname2 name2, middlename2.....`

I need to get people from EMPLOYEES who are in the STAFF.

query

```
SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, MIDDENAME  from EMPLOYEES  where 
CONCAT('%', LASTNAME, ' ', NAME, ' ',MIDDENAME, '%') 
like (SELECT STAFF FROM PROJECTS)
```

doesn't work because LIKE must have one substring from 2nd query

and query

```
SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, MIDDENAME  from  EMPLOYEES  where 
CONCAT('%', LASTNAME, ' ', NAME, ' ',MIDDENAME, '%') 
IN (SELECT STAFF FROM PROJECTS)
```

doesn't work too because for IN need full matching

any ideas?

Comment: Please consider formatting your post.

Comment: Provide your table definitions and some sample data set to test

Comment: I would suggest that name strings (though it may seem like a good idea) are a poor idea for entity intersects

Comment: That's what happens when you have delimited string like that in table which is against normalization.

Comment: if I had this data model, I would punt on 2nd down

Comment: so I need to rename NAME column?

Comment: I would spend the time crafting a good data model, rather than patching a shabby one. If you post your schema, you could get some advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what happens when you have delimited string like that in table which is against normalization. First consider normalizing your table. For now, you can perform a `JOIN` probably like below but if `STAFF` column has data in exact in format else matching will not occur.

```
SELECT e.LASTNAME, e.NAME, e.MIDDENAME  
FROM EMPLOYEES e 
JOIN PROJECTS p
ON CONCAT(e.LASTNAME, ' ', e.NAME, ' ', e.MIDDENAME) = p.STAFF;
```

You can as well use `FIND_IN_SET()` function like below but again consider changing your DB design first and Normalize your table(s)

```
   SELECT LASTNAME, 
          NAME, 
          MIDDENAME
   FROM (
    SELECT LASTNAME, NAME, 
    MIDDENAME,
    CONCAT(e.LASTNAME, ' ', e.NAME, ' ', e.MIDDENAME) as Full_Name  
    FROM EMPLOYEES) e 
    JOIN PROJECTS p
    ON  FIND_IN_SET(Full_Name, p.STAFF) > 0;
```

Comment: It works only if STAFF contains one employee. But a lot of rows in STAFF looks like 'lastname1, name1, middlename1; lastname2, name2, middlename2........lastnameN, nameN, middlenameN'

Comment: @Vitaly, that's what I said that your table design is bad as it stands now. Consider normalizing it first. See edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I made some changes (used LIKE and '%'): SELECT e.LASTNAME, e.NAME, e.MIDDENAME FROM EMPLOYEES e JOIN PROJECTS p ON p.STAFF LIKE CONCAT('%', e.LASTNAME, ' ', e.NAME, ' ', e.MIDDLENAME, '%'); It works well! Rahul, thanks a lot!